# How to get categorical variable correlation matrix using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a dataframe like as shown below. You just run the below code snippets as is and you will know what the error is. Guess mistake is in the for loop

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'sub_code' : ['CSE01', 'CSE01', 'CSE01', 
                   'CSE02', 'CSE03', 'CSE04',
                   'CSE05', 'CSE06'],
     'stud_level' : [101, 101, 101, 101, 
                  101, 101, 101, 101],
     'grade' : ['STA','STA','PSA','STA','STA','SSA','PSA','QSA']})
```

I am trying to find the categorical correlation using the below code (found from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/chrisbss1/cramer-s-v-correlation-matrix)).
The correlation values generated are correct but am making mistake with the matrix constriction using for loop. my results repeat and occur 4 rows instead of 2 rows. I deal with big data, so any efficient approach is also welcome

Can help me with this?

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
label = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
data_encoded = pd.DataFrame() 
for i in df.columns:
    data_encoded[i]=label.fit_transform(df[i])
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
import numpy as np
def cramers_V(var1,var2) :
    crosstab =np.array(pd.crosstab(var1,var2, rownames=None, colnames=None)) # Cross table building
    stat = chi2_contingency(crosstab)[0] # Keeping of the test statistic of the Chi2 test
    obs = np.sum(crosstab) # Number of observations
    mini = min(crosstab.shape)-1 # Take the minimum value between the columns and the rows of the cross table
    return (stat/(obs*mini))

rows=[]  
for var1 in data_encoded.columns.tolist(): #guess am making mistake here
    col=[]
    for var2 in data_encoded.columns.tolist(): #guess am making mistake here
        cramers =cramers_V(data_encoded[var1], data_encoded[var2])
        col.append(round(cramers,2))
        rows.append(col)
cramers_results = np.array(rows) # issue could be here as well
df = pd.DataFrame(cramers_results,columns = data_encoded.columns, index=data_encoded.columns) # issue is here
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below but am making some mistake with correlation matrix construction. My values are computed correctly in the code above but issue is with matrix construction

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by fixing the alignment of below statement

```
rows.append(col)
```

For loop code is given below

```
for var2 in data_encoded.columns.tolist(): 
    cramers =cramers_V(data_encoded[var1], data_encoded[var2])
    col.append(round(cramers,2))
rows.append(col) # fixed the alignment issue
```

`rows` stmt has to be out of for loop (not inside the for loop like in my question post)

Rest of the code is fine and produces perfect output

[image]